# loading content on scroll event don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to make a script that load content from a web service when user scroll to the bottom of the page this is my JS code :

```js
var serviceURL = "http://projects.dev/work/";
var current_page = 1;
var total_pages = 1;
$(function() {
    Init();
});

function Init() {
 getPosts();
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if((($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height())+20)>=$(document).height()){
   if(current_page <= total_pages){ 
    getPosts();
   }
  }
 }); 
}
function getPosts(){
 $.ajax({
  url:serviceURL+"api/posts?page="+current_page,
  dataType: "json",
  async : false,
  cache : false,
 }).then( function(data){
  total_pages = data.last_page;
   $.each(data.data, function(index, post) {
    $('#newsList').append("<li>"+
      "<aside><img src='"+serviceURL+"cdn/"+post.picture+"'></aside>"+
      "<div>"+
      "<a href='post.html?id="+post.id+"'><h3>"+post.title+"</h3></a>"+
      "<h4>"+post.created_at.split(" ")[0]+"</h4>"+
      "</div>"+
   "</li>");
   });
   $("#loading").hide("slow");
  current_page++;
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
  <body>
  <div id="loading"><div id="loading-spin"></div></div>
  <header><div id="brand">News</div>
    <a href="index.html" class="medIcons left" id="back"></a>
  </header>
  <article style="width:100%;margin:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;padding-left:0 !important;">
  <ul id="newsList"></ul>
  
  </article>
  




  
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/posts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

can you tell me whats wrong ? i can get only posts from the first time and then nothing happen when i scroll to the bottom of the page .
PS : i have a lot of posts , and the last_page variable is the total of pages i have on my DB .

Comment: Have you tried debugging a bit? Does your getPosts() function get called?

Comment: @RusPaul no it not called

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it , i  had to remove overflow:hidden from the container .
thanks .